# Comparing Map Of strings with map of Objects

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<String,String>` object and also a `Map<String,Object>` one.

Now I ned to pick an entry from `Map<String,String>` and find that entry in `Map<String,Object>` and find out the data type for the value and convert the `Map<string, String>` entry value to the corresponding matching data type in `Map<String, Object` and compare these 2 values.

For Example:

```
Map map1=  new HashMap<String,string>();
map.put("a","strValue");
map.put("b","10");
map.put("c","10.00");
map.put("d","true");

Map map2=  new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("a","strValue");
map.put("b",10);
map.put("c",10.00);
map.put("d",true);
map.put("e",45);
map.put("f","SAM");
map.put("g",false);
```

Now I need to find all the corresponding matches in `map1` to `map2`.

Example: if I take an entry from map1 it will be string `string(a, StrValue)`.
Then find that entry key in map 2 and compare these two values by converting corresponding types. And repeat this lesson until the map1 elements are complete and final result should be if any of the value in map1 doesnot match with map2 value ignore this result and if all the values matches then I need to perform some updates store that `map<String, Object>` Object into DB.

In real time I will have `List<Map<String,Object>`. I need to filter all matching values in the `map<String, Object>`.

Is there a better design or approach to solve this problem.

Comment: When asking for a better approach, you should at least give us your baseline approach that you want to improve.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that those two maps are not a fit data structure; it is more like doing ones own type system. However here an approach:

Taking the toString of the objects for comparison of the map's value will not do.
`Objects.toString(10.30)` will not necessarily be `"10.3"` and most likely not `"10.30"`.

So you will cannot simply use `Objects.toString(Object)` to convert everything, even `null` to a `String` and then compare. For floating point you need an imprecise matching, an almost-equals function.

You could use custom tests for values: `BiPredicate<Object, String>`.

```
private static Map<<Class<?>, BiPredicate<Object, String>> similars = new HashMap<>();
static {
    similars.put(String.class, (obj, repr) -> repr.equalsIgnoreCase((String) obj));
    similars.put(Integer.class, (obj, repr) -> Integer.parseInt(repr) == (Integer) obj);
    similars.put(Double.class, (obj, repr) ->
                               Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(repr) - (Double) obj) < 0.0001);
    ...
}

boolean valuesAreAlmostEqual(Object value, String valueRepr) {
    if (value == null) {
        return valueRepr.equals("null");
    }
    BiPredicate<Object, String> similar = similarMap.get(value.getClass());
    if (similar == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Uncovered value class " + value.getClass().getName());
    }
    return similar.test(value, valueRepr);
}
```